# Server code keeps executing after Ajax timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I have this Ajax code in jquery to call a php function, i'm putting a very low timeout for testing purposes, the timeout code gets executed as planned but the server keeps running the code of my call.

So its confusing because the user gets a timeout error, but after some time the code on the server gets completed.

Is there a way to stop the server from running the code after my ajax timeout is called? or is there something im using wrong with the timeout?

```
$.ajax({
            url: CI.base_url + 'admin/comprobantes/validarPago',
            type: "POST",
            timeout: 10,
            data: {comp_id:comp_id},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('entra al response');
                var response = JSON.parse(response);
                that.prop('disabled', false);
                that.html('Validar');
                if(response.redirect == 1){
                    location.href = CI.base_url + 'login_admin/index/1';
                } else if(response.error){
                    crearNotificacion('Error', response.mensaje, 'error');
                    return false;
                }else{
                    console.log(response);
                    crearNotificacion('Éxito', response.mensaje, 'success');
                    $('#tablaComprobantes').bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                        silent: true
                    });
                    $('#modalValidarComprobante').modal('toggle');
                    return false;         
                } 
            },
            error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
                that.prop('disabled', false);
                that.html('Validar');
                console.log('entra al timeout');
                if(textstatus==="timeout") {
                    crearNotificacion('Error', 'La acción esta tardando mucho en completarse, favor de revisar tu conexión a internet, da "Actualizar" a la página e inténtalo de nuevo.', 'error', '6000');
                } else {
                    crearNotificacion('Error', textstatus, 'error', '6000');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The timeout is only for the contract between the request and a response.  The server doesn't stop what it's doing.  Using the pizza analogy:  you phone-order a pizza and leave your front door open for the delivery person; pizza place starts cooking your pizza;  you get bored after 30mins and close your front door.  The pizza is still being cooked / being delivered, you've just closed the communication channel (your front door).  The ajax timeout/error is raised when you close the door.  If you also want to cancel the pizza you then need to (separately) call them back up to cancel it.

Comment: thanks, i understand this, but in this case, how can i call the pizza and cancel it?

Comment: You would need a separate end point on your server/service and a mechanism within the original service method to check if that had been called.   A simple example might be (and excuse the formatting in a comment)  `var stopme = false; function runme() { while(not_complete) { do_something(); if (stopme) { break; } } function stoptherun() { stopme = true; }`  this won't work in js which is single-threaded but something similar should work server-side.  Depends on what the server-side is doing and if there's a way to break into it.  eg a complicated SQL call would be much hard to break into